# Accessing device with broken touch sensor and LCD using adb

Tags: adb, sd-card, usb-debugging, file-management, broken-screen

After a drop, my phone's (Galaxy J3 6v) screen (both LCD and touch sensor) are completely unresponsive. I believe I have USB debugging turned on, but cannot be sure. 
I have a Linux machine with android-tools installed, and am comfortable with the command line.
I've been trying to connect with adb, but it gives me the error:

```
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

I have already killed and restarted the server, added udev rules, and added the phones vendor id to .android/adb_usb.ini, as well as called Samsung support (they had no clue what I was going on about)

Am I SOL, or is there a way to bypass the confirmation dialogue?

Comment: Adb connection has to be authorized by the user in the phone. When a connection is to be established a dialog is shown to the user for approval in the phone, pending which adb would remain unauthorised.

Comment: so without a way to interact or even see what is going on on the phones side, I'm SOL?

Comment: You could try to use a usb mouse/keyboard for the approval dialog on the phone otherwise adb will only connect to approved PCs/Macs.

Answer (score 0):

You are being prompted to accept the dialog on screen,

You obviously have no option to actually accept the dialog, so your chances of getting around this are low.

You may be able to swap between USB OTG mouse and USB cord to accept the dialog and then swap back to continue in ADB...

If you are serious about repairing the device or at least recovering the data, a last resort would be to just replace the digitizer and LCD ... 
[Cheap Digitizer & LCD on EBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Fit-For-Samsung-Galaxy-J3-2016-J320-LCD-Display-Touch-Screen-Digitizer-Parts/163035923265?hash=item25f5b2c341:m:m-_b9QCReh2kt6gehZrJlRQ)